# Python: Map a function over recursive iterables

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have an arbitrarily nested iterable like so:

```
numbers = (1, 2, (3, (4, 5)), 7)
```

and I'd like to map a function over it without changing the structure. For example, I might want to convert all the numbers to strings to get

```
strings = recursive_map(str, numbers)
assert strings == ('1', '2', ('3', ('4', '5')), '7')
```

Is there a nice way to do this? I can imaging writing my own method to manually traverse `numbers`, but I'd like to know if there's a general way to map over recursive iterables.

Also, in my example, it's okay if `strings` gives me nested lists (or some iterable) rather nested tuples.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We scan every element in the sequence, and proceeds into deeper recursion if the current item is a sub-sequence, or yields it's mapping if we reached a non-sequence data type (could be `int`, `str`, or any complex classes).

We use `collections.Sequence` to generalize the idea for every sequence, and not only tuples or lists, and `type(item)` upon yield to ensure that the sub-sequences we get back remains of the same type they were.

```
from collections import Sequence

def recursive_map(seq, func):
    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, Sequence):
            yield type(item)(recursive_map(item, func))
        else:
            yield func(item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> numbers = (1, 2, (3, (4, 5)), 7)
>>> mapped = recursive_map(numbers, str)
>>> tuple(mapped)
('1', '2', ('3', ('4', '5')), '7')
```

Or a more complex example:

```
>>> complex_list = (1, 2, [3, (complex('4+2j'), 5)], map(str, (range(7, 10))))
>>> tuple(recursive_map(complex_list, lambda x: x.__class__.__name__))
('int', 'int', ['int', ('complex', 'int')], 'map')
```

Comment: I believe you are only generalizing to *sequences*. Whether something is an iterable is not an issue of type but of following a protocol. OP may mean sequence, but this won't iterate over sets, ducts, etc. Whether or not something is an iterable is defined by whether it implements the iterable protocol

Comment: Worth noting that this is solution broken since Python 3.10, as `Sequence` is provided by `collections.abc` (and has been since Python 3.3, so this can be adjusted without breaking compatibility with any commonly-used Python versions).

Answer (score 6):

```
def recursive_map(f, it):
    return (recursive_map(f, x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else f(x) for x in it)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to extend your result to `dict`, `set` and others, you can use Uriel's answer:

```
from collections import Collection, Mapping

def recursive_map(data, func):
    apply = lambda x: recursive_map(x, func)
    if isinstance(data, Mapping):
        return type(data)({k: apply(v) for k, v in data.items()})
    elif isinstance(data, Collection):
        return type(data)(apply(v) for v in data)
    else:
        return func(data)
```

Tests input:

```
recursive_map({0: [1, {2, 2, 3}]}, str)
```

Yields:

```
{0: ['1', '{2, 3}']}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for sets. Change Sequence to Collection to make it work.

Comment: @fjsj Thank you. I changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I extended the notion of a recursive map to work on the standard python collections: list, dict, set, tuple:

```
def recursiveMap(something, func):
  if isinstance(something, dict):
    accumulator = {}
    for key, value in something.items():
      accumulator[key] = recursiveMap(value, func)
    return accumulator
  elif isinstance(something, (list, tuple, set)):
    accumulator = []
    for item in something:
      accumulator.append(recursiveMap(item, func))
    return type(something)(accumulator)
  else:
    return func(something)
```

This passes the following tests, which I'll include mostly as examples of usage:

```
from hypothesis                 import given
from hypothesis.strategies      import dictionaries, text
from server.utils               import recursiveMap


def test_recursiveMap_example_str():
  assert recursiveMap({'a': 1}, str) == {'a': '1'}
  assert recursiveMap({1: 1}, str) == {1: '1'}
  assert recursiveMap({'a': {'a1': 12}, 'b': 2}, str) == {'a': {'a1': '12'}, 'b': '2'}
  assert recursiveMap([1, 2, [31, 32], 4], str) == ['1', '2', ['31', '32'], '4']
  assert recursiveMap((1, 2, (31, 32), 4), str) ==  ('1', '2', ('31', '32'), '4')
  assert recursiveMap([1, 2, (31, 32), 4], str) ==  ['1', '2', ('31', '32'), '4']


@given(dictionaries(text(), text()))
def test_recursiveMap_noop(dictionary):
  assert recursiveMap(dictionary, lambda x: x) == dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone before has mentioned the number of things one might possibly need for any flavour of a `flatten` function, but there was something that I've been playing with as an exercise in learning the language (so Python noob alert) that I didn't see quite put together here. Basically I wanted for my `flatten` to be able to handle any `Iterable`s, of any length and nesting in the most efficient (time and space) way possible. This lead me to the generator pattern, and the first requirement I posed for my function was nothing to be created before its time.

My other requirement was the absence of any *explicit* looping (for/while) because why not: at least since the helpful addition of `yield from` in Python 3.3 I was pretty sure it was possible. It would have to be recursive of course, but getting it to give a proper, "flat" generator proved trickier than I thought. So here's my 2p, illustrating the wonderful `chain` and, I suspect, the kind of situation (a bit more abstracted of course) it was made for:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(items):
    if isinstance(items,Iterable):
        yield from chain(*map(flatten,items))    
    else:
        yield items

items = [0xf, [11, 22, [23, (33,(4, 5))], 66, [], [77]], [8,8], 99, {42}]
print(list(flatten(items)))
```

Unfortunately for my for-free ambitious project (and ego), according to some pretty rough benchmarking this is ~30% slower than the version using `for`:

```
def flatten(items):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item,Iterable):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

a variant of which was already given by Uriel. I hope it is however a good illustration of the flexibility and power of Python used in a quasi-functional way, especially for others new to the language.

Edit: to avoid splitting up strings in individual list items, one can append `and not isinstance(item,(str,bytes))` to the conditional. And other various bells and whistles that would detract from the point.