# How to Convert List of Numbers to Integers in Python?

Tags: python, list

So I have a list of lists of numbers from a .txt file loaded in Python:

```
ls = [['3456', '937'], ['3666', '54533'], ['24456', '83279'], ['344516', '10410']...]
```

How can I convert the numbers (`type: list`) to integers type, but keep them in this list?

I.e. the output I'd like:

```
[[3456, 937], [3666, 54533], [24456, 83279], [344516, 10410]...]
```

I've tried using this:

```
ls = [int(i) for i in ls]
```

But get the error: int() argument must be a string.

Does anyone know how to do the conversion to the output I'd like? Thanks!

Comment: A more generalized solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095393/python-map-a-function-over-recursive-iterables

Comment: It's a list of lists of strings that represent numbers, not a list of lists of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one more comprehension inside:

```
ls = [[int(i) for i in k] for k in ls]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and list comprehension.

```
ls = [['3456', '937'], ['3666', '54533'], ['24456', '83279'], ['344516', '10410']]

>>> [list(map(int, i)) for i in ls]
#[[3456, 937], [3666, 54533], [24456, 83279], [344516, 10410]]
```

Comment: That's really no different from the code in the question, and I'm sure it will fail with the same error.

Comment: It does not fail at all. `map` accepts an iterable. `map(function, iterable)` code is working as is in Python 3.8. Updated answer to show result.

Comment: I just tried it, my apologies.  Of course `map` works on iterables, that's its job.

Answer (score 0):

List is mutable but string is not. You can use for loop to achieve this.

```
print(id(a[0]))
print(id(a[0][0]))

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        a[i][j] = int(a[i][j])

print(a)
print(type(a[0][0]))
print(id(a[0])) # the same id with the first print
print(id(a[0][1])) # id has changed
```