# JSON traversal and editing in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a number of JSON responses that looks like below

```
{
    "response": {
        "list": [
            {
                "key1": "val1",
                "key2": "val2"
            },
            {
                "key3": "val3",
                "key4": ""
            }
        ],
        "data": {
            "key5": "val5",
            "key6": "",
            "key7": "val7"
        },
        "key8": "val8",
        "key9": "val9",
        "key10": "",
        "key10": "val10"
    }
}
```

Some JSON responses may be a completely different structure. Some may have more inner lists and dicts and some may be a simple flat json
I need to replace all the empty strings ("") with a Null/None value.
I am not sure how to traverse an unknown JSON while replacing the values.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't change the json. Load it into python data strucutes with json.loads, make the changes there, then overwrite the whole json file. Here's something sort of similar for the middle step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095393/python-map-a-function-over-recursive-iterables/42095505

Comment: With `jq`, one would simply write something like `jq 'walk(select(.=="")|=null)' tmp.json`. There exist [Python bindings for the `jq` library](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) that let you do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use the [Python `jq` bindings](https://pypi.org/project/jq/), which allow you to write a short filter to process the JSON before decoding it.

```
response = '''{
    "response": {
        "list": [
            {
                "key1": "val1",
                "key2": "val2"
            },
            {
                "key3": "val3",
                "key4": ""
            }
        ],
        "data": {
            "key5": "val5",
            "key6": "",
            "key7": "val7"
        },
        "key8": "val8",
        "key9": "val9",
        "key10": "",
        "key10": "val10"
    }
}'''

>>> jq.all('walk(select(.=="")|=null)', text=response)[0]
{'response': {'list': [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, {'key3': 'val3', 'key4': None}], 'data': {'key5': 'val5', 'key6': None, 'key7': 'val7'}, 'key8': 'val8', 'key9': 'val9', 'key10': 'val10'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way without a library is to create and use a recursive function:

```py
def replace_blanks(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: replace_blanks(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return [replace_blanks(elem) for elem in o]
    return None if o == '' else o
```

Usage:

```py
from pprint import pprint


d = {
    "response": {
        "list": [
            {
                "key1": "val1",
                "key2": "val2"
            },
            {
                "key3": "val3",
                "key4": ""
            }
        ],
        "data": {
            "key5": "val5",
            "key6": "",
            "key7": "val7"
        },
        "key8": "val8",
        "key9": "val9",
        "key10": "",
        "key10": "val10"
    }
}

pprint(replace_blanks(d))
```

Prints:

```
{'response': {'data': {'key5': 'val5', 'key6': None, 'key7': 'val7'},
              'key10': 'val10',
              'key8': 'val8',
              'key9': 'val9',
              'list': [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'},
                       {'key3': 'val3', 'key4': None}]}}
```

If your data is a JSON string and you're trying to load it to a Python object, you can also pass the `object_hook` argument to `json.loads`:

```py
json_string = """
{"response": {"list": [{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, {"key3": "val3", "key4": ""}],
              "data": {"key5": "val5", "key6": "", "key7": "val7"},
              "key8": "val8", "key9": "val9", "key10": "val10"}}
"""

data = json.loads(json_string, object_hook=replace_blanks)
pprint(data)
```