# change variables in an unknown python structure

Tags: python, object, nested, structure, primitive

Lets say i have a list or dictionary, each one contains many dictionaries, lists, sets,string,floats, and so on.
every time i need to handle different structure, but what i know is that all the strings (some of them in different level of nesting) have some extra spaces in them, so i need to trim them using :

```
if (type(variable)==str):
    variable=variable.strip()
```

How can i access all these variables given an unknown structure being = `[' 1',2,3,{},[[],{}],9,9]` or maybe `{'1:2,2:[],9:[],10:[[[]]]}` ?
In case of dictionaries, the keys are ok (trimming won't change anything, so i don't mind doing it), just need to change the values
Is there an elegant function for this?

Comment: Use recursion and check for the type of the values, then handle each type separately

Comment: You will have to know at least **something** about the data structure. Is it always going to be a list of other containers?

Comment: the main structure is probably a list or dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Map a function over recursive iterables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095393/python-map-a-function-over-recursive-iterables)

Comment: @vaizki this is not a good solution because it treats string like sequence. also it does not treat values of dictionaries. changed it to treat string as non sequence, but still:
tuple(recursive_map([1,2,3,'  5  ',{'f':'  s  ','d':'  1  '},'  d  ',['  1','  3  ',2]], st_strip))
Out[76]: (1, 2, 3, '5', {'d': '  1  ', 'f': '  s  '}, 'd', ['1', '3', 2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of recursion and checking for types will let you process a structure in a predetermined way without knowing its exact structure beforehand. You need to know how each specific container should be handled though.

```
variable = {'1':2,2:[],9:[],10:[[[]]]}

def custom_strip(variable):
    if isinstance(variable, dict):
        for k, v in variable.items():
            variable[k] = custom_strip(v)
        return variable
    if isinstance(variable, list):
        return [custom_strip(v) for v in variable]
    if isinstance(variable, set):
        return {custom_strip(v) for v in variable}
    if isinstance(variable, float) or isinstance(variable, int):
        return variable + 1
    if isinstance(variable, str):
        return variable.strip()
    raise TypeError("Unknown type")

print(custom_strip(variable))
```

Comment: thank you! but why did you write "return variable + 1" ?

Comment: Just to see that the values are in fact changed.

Comment: your answer looks pretty good, i would like to try it. can you please add pandas.series to the function? seems like currently i am working with pandas DataFrame, and would like to change it.

Comment: ok i added the series. but your code does not handle set well.
given custom_strip({'f1','f2'}) i get  94]: <generator object custom_strip.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001E5B501C9E8>5]

Comment: @Matan Yeah, wrong brackets in comprehension statement, should be `{ }` not `( )`. Corrected.